Keycloak NextAuth Timeout Error with Cloud Run and GCE
I'm deploying a website using authentication via Keycloak. The frontend of the website is deployed on Google Cloud Run, and the Keycloak server is running in a container on a Google Compute Engine instance. The frontend is built using Nextjs and the authentication is configured via NextAuth.
When running the frontend server locally, I am able to connect to the Keycloak instance running in the Compute Engine and successfully go through the login process. However, in deployment, when I click on the login button (which calls the NextAuth 'signOut' function), it times out and redirects to a screen like this:
error screen
With the Cloud Run error log reading:
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616627Z https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error outgoing request timed out after 3500ms {
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616633Z error: {
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616639Z message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms',
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616648Z stack: 'i: outgoing request timed out after 3500ms\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616654Z ' at /app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:39:37437\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616659Z ' at async _.discover (/app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:39:42108)\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616665Z ' at async o (/app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:6:125880)\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616670Z ' at async s (/app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:6:118226)\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616675Z ' at async Object.s (/app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:30:8621)\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616680Z ' at async _ (/app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:6:103586)\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616685Z ' at async a (/app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:30:19579)\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616690Z ' at async e.length.t (/app/.next/server/chunks/312.js:30:20990)\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616695Z ' at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:34666\n' +
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616701Z ' at async eS.execute (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:25813)',
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616706Z name: 'i'
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616710Z },
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616715Z providerId: 'keycloak',
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616721Z message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms'
DEFAULT 2024-07-11T21:13:09.616726Z }


For reference, my NextAuth Keycloak provider options are set up like this:
providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "openid email profile",
        },
        url: process.env.KEYCLOAK_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
      },
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name ?? profile.preferred_username,
          has_onboarded: profile.has_onboarded,
          email: profile.email,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],

And the environment variables are configured according to the documentation.
How do I get the login button working?
Based on other results online, I have tried:

setting the timeout to 100 seconds
deleting the defined "NEXTAUTH_URL" in the environment variables
many permutations of the issuer environment variable

And nothing has worked so far. I suspect the issue revolves around Cloud Run communicating effectively with Compute Engine, although I have not been able to pinpoint the problem. Both instances are configured to accept traffic from anywhere.

I found the solution. Inside of our Cloud Run settings, we were routing all outbound traffic through our VPC, which both the Cloud Run instance and the GCE instance were apart of.

We switched to select "Route only requests to private IPs to the VPC" as pictured.
Setting located in Edit and Deploy new revision > Networking tab > "Connect to a VPC for outbound traffic" checkbox
